# Ireport parameter count calculation difficulties

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report that has can take in 4 parameters in my report designer

ex: **ticket1 , ticket2 , ticket3 , ticket4**.

sometimes I can choose to give the report 2 parameters or maybe 3

ex: **ticket1 , ticket2**  or **ticket1 , ticket2 , ticket3**

I have a variable TICKET_COUNT , I don't know how to sum up the count of the  paremeters since I may not always give it 4, I could give any from 0 to 4.

How can I get the number of parameters that I give to the report??

ex: ticket1 , ticket2 , ticket3 , ticket4. TICKET_COUNT = 4

ex: ticket1  , ticket4. TICKET_COUNT = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

write a scriptlet

```
package com.xxx;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;

public class MyScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
 public int getTicketCount() throws JRScriptletException {
     String ticket1 = (String)this.getParameterValue("ticket1");
     String ticket2 = (String)this.getParameterValue("ticket2");
     String ticket3 = (String)this.getParameterValue("ticket3");
     String ticket4 = (String)this.getParameterValue("ticket4");
     int cnt = 0;
     if(ticket1!=null){
         cnt++;
     }
     if(ticket2!=null){
         cnt++;
     }
     if(ticket3!=null){
         cnt++;
     }
     if(ticket4!=null){
         cnt++;
     }
     return cnt;
   }
}
```

build the scriptlet to a jar file and in the report go to classpath and add the jar

set the Scritplet property of the report with the full qualified name
of your scriptlet class(ex: com.xxx.MyScriptlet)

In the report create the variable TICKET_COUNT and

set variable class to `java.lang.Integer`

set variable expression to `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getTicketCount()`

scriptlet configuration details [here](http://www.opus-college.net/devcorner/iReport-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) (chapter 15 scriptlets)